# Know this "maximum of sums towards minimum" distribution?

Tags: math, statistics, probability-distribution

Let we have *N* integer slots initially containing 0's and an infinite sequence of similar independent negative binomial variables *w<sub>i</sub>* ~ NB(*l*, *q*). Each next value from the sequence is added to the slot containing the minimal value. The question is: what is the distribution of the step number at which any of the slots exceeds given limit *k*?

If you ask, it's a simplified model of attack on vulnerable ("one unit lost means all die") stack of units in Freeciv game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Actually, I am thinking about how to impruve the game battle system and need this in some computations, so for me it is... Sorry, new here, could misplace thing.

Comment: Interesting question; it seems like a question in random walks or martingales or something of that flavor. Try math.stackexchange.com, I think they'll like this question.

Comment: Ok, I have posted it there: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355335/a-distribution-of-maximum-of-sums-if-add-to-the-minimal